# Use of commas in street names in text

Tags: grammar

Is a comma required after a direction (NE, NW, SE, SW) when a street name is used in text?

For example:

> One path would continue down the eastern side of the hill, terminating
>   at the Maine Avenue and 9th Street, SW intersection

Comment: The answer depends entirely on local convention and postal regulation, not the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean in Washington D.C. addresses? Yes, commas are usually inserted before and after the quadrant.

You would say

> 1101 6th Street, SW, is the address.

Since Maine Avenue and 6th Street only intersect once in D.C., you don't actually need to put the quadrant in, but if you do use it, people would generally put commas before and after it.

> the Maine Avenue and 6th Street, SW, intersection.

In [Seattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_layout_of_Seattle) and Minneapolis addresses, on the other hand, the quadrant is ***not*** usually separated with commas.

> 415 1st Ave. N, Seattle.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of style, but perhaps it's best to heed the arbiter of mailing addresses, the United States Postal Service.  In their webpage entitled "[A Customer's Guide to Mailing](http://pe.usps.com/text/dmm100/addressing-mail.htm)" they say two relevant things about quadrant addresses.  First,

> If the address also has a **directional** (for instance, **NW** for Northwest), be sure to use it. There may be more than one Main Street.

The USPS consider directionals definitional, not parenthetical.  This would point to omitting the preceding comma, and sure enough, secondly:

> Do not use commas or periods.

From sea to shining sea, addresses do not use commas:

[Sea](https://www.whitehouse.gov/contact/write-or-call):

> The White House
> 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW
> Washington, DC 20500

[Shining sea](http://www.seattlechildrens.org):

> Seattle Children's
> 4800 Sand Point Way NE Seattle WA 98105

Comment: The White House may not use a comma, but the [Smithsonian Institution](http://www.si.edu/Visit/Maps) does. And when I lived in Washington, D.C., many years ago, the commas were definitely correct in addresses.

Comment: @PeterShor This isn't a matter of correctness; it's a matter of style.  The Smithsonian is out of style, and you used to be.  I intend to inform the Postal Inspectors about the both of you.

Comment: For mailing addresses, the Post Office recommends *"Pennsylvania Ave"* with no period, but in almost any other situation, you would use *"Pennsylvania Ave." with a period.* The directive *"do not use commas or periods"* (which even the White House did not follow completely) is intended to help automatic text recognition programs sort mail, and not as a general style guide.

Answer (score 1):

No comma is required. If you want to use one, use two, one on either side of the directional notation, by way of treating it as parenthetical. (If the directional notation ends the sentence, however, of course the following period will close the parenthesis as well as closing the sentence, and no second comma will be needed or wanted.) But the no-comma option is probably preferable, as a smoother read.

Answer (score 0):

In much of the Midwest, at least, the compass point designation is usually considered to be a part of the street name.  That is, "5th Street NW" is considered to be the name of the street.  As such, there should be no comma between "Street" and "NW".

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues discussed in previous responses that shouldn't be confused:  writing the address in a text/narrative, and addressing items for mailing.

Anyone referencing USPS standards should understand that those standards are designed to ensure rapid, accurate handling by automated mail systems.  USPS guidelines direct that punctuation is not used in addresses or state abbreviations (including DC).

In grammatical usage, however, the best answer seems to me to be local custom.  Given that the original question specified "in text", I'd go with Peter Shor's response over deadrat's.  DC addresses get the comma, Seattle doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As an editor in the nation's capital, I've had to grapple with the comma question and even the Smithsonian's outdated style recently. @petershor, Chicago Style is very clear that no comma precedes the compass point. @deadrat is correct, the Smithsonian is out of style, but that's their right I suppose.

Herewith the operative CMOS example: "I stayed in a building on N Street SW, close to the city center." (10.34 Chicago Style 17th edition)

On the intersection question posed by @maggie67, I would recast thusly: "... terminating at the intersection of 9th Street SW and Maine Avenue."

Comment: Hello, Paul. Peter is differentiating what he states to be (or have been)  separate practices in  Washington DC and other cities. These things are usage-driven; I doubt that any US style guide has actually researched individual cities to check on prevalence. In any case, these disputes become very arbitrary. I've seen 'rules' spelling out the 'proper use of apostrophes' in place names, but at least two of St James's Park in London, St James' Park in Newcastle and St James Park in Exeter ignore them.